# magento pay some part of order payment at checkout and rest after delivery

Tags: php, magento

i want to create / add custom method where user have to pay some percent of total order at checkout say 50% of order amount and rest amount he will have to pay when order gets delivered how can i do that.
What observer do i need to check for that ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to call observer before checkout see 
http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/